# Why doesn't pagination and column selection work in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, pagination

I am doing pagination; I want to select all elements of a particular column, but I am getting only those values which are currently available on the page.

Here is my code:

```
var vals = new Array();
var i=0;
var options='';
jQuery('#SearchResultsTable123 tr:gt(0)  td:nth-child(2)').each(function(){
   var t=jQuery(this).html();
   if(jQuery.inArray(t, vals) < 0)
   {
      vals[i]=t;
      i++;
   }
}); 

for(var j=0;j<i;j++)
{
   options +=     vals[j] +':' ;
}
alert(options);
```

This code gives me the distinct value of that column but only for visible page.

Comment: is all the content available in the html?

Answer (score 0):

By visible do you mean retrieved  data or all the table data is already in the page but some are invisible?

If you data is not all in the html you have to do this with your server side technology or ajax. or else you have to append all your data at first so you can get the column value for everything